# How to use a class in another class in Arduino C++ (FastLED)?

Tags: c++, class, arduino, arduino-c++

I am working on an ledstip project for my room. I am using arduino to do this. For this project i want to use C++ so i can use OOP. After i got my ledstrips working I wanted to create a cluster class that used the strip class to control a specific piece of the LED strip. I can't get this to work. The compiler gives no errors and I see no change after using the function `Desk.rgb(0,100,0);`.

Here is my .h file

```
#include <FastLED.h>
template<class T>
class Cluster {
  public:
    T Strip;
    int first;
    int last;

    Cluster(T Strip, int first, int last) {
      this->Strip = Strip;
      this->first = first;
      this->last = last;
    }
    
    void rgb(int r, int g, int b){
      Strip.rgb( r,  g,  b, first, last);
    }
};

template<byte pin, int AmountOfLeds>
class Strip {
  public:
    CRGB leds[AmountOfLeds];

    void setup() {
      FastLED.addLeds<WS2812, pin, GRB>(leds, AmountOfLeds);
      rgb(0, 0, 0);
    }
    //hole strip
    void rgb(int r, int g, int b) {
      for (int i = 0; i <= AmountOfLeds - 1; i++) {
        this->leds[i] = CRGB(r, g, b);
      }
      FastLED.show();
    }
    //single led
    void rgb(int i, int r, int g, int b) {
      this->leds[i] = CRGB(r, g, b);
      FastLED.show();
    }
    //range
    void rgb(int r, int g, int b, int f, int l) {
      for (int i = f; i <= l; i++) {
        this->leds[i] = CRGB(r, g, b);
      }
      FastLED.show();
    }

    void hsv(int h, int s, int v) {
      for (int i = 0; i <= AmountOfLeds; i++) {
        this->leds[i] = CHSV(h, s, v);
      }
      FastLED.show();
    }
    void hsv(int i, int h, int s, int v) {
      this->leds[i] = CHSV(h, s, v);
      FastLED.show();
    }
    void hsv(int h, int s, int v, int f, int l) {
      for (int i = f; i <= l; i++) {
        this->leds[i] = CHSV(h, s, v);
      }
      FastLED.show();
    }

    void hsvWhiteBalance(int S, int V) {         //S is yellowness, V is brightness
      hsv(15, S, V);
    }

    void rainbow(float V) {
      for (int i = 0; i <= AmountOfLeds; i++) {
        leds[i] = CHSV( float(i) * (255 / float(AmountOfLeds)), 255, V);
      }
      FastLED.show();
    }
    void rainbow(float p, float V) {
      for (int i = 0; i <= AmountOfLeds; i++) {
        leds[i] = CHSV( float(i) * (255.0 / float(AmountOfLeds) * p), 255, V);
      }
      FastLED.show();
    }
};
```

This is my .ino file:

```
#include "LedClasses.h"
Strip<5, 190> DTVC;

Cluster<Strip<5, 190>> Desk(DTVC, 1, 42);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);   

  DTVC.setup();

  DTVC.hsvWhiteBalance(153, 50);
  Desk.rgb(0,100,0);
  //DTVC.rgb(Desk, 0, 100, 0);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't work, because in the `Cluster` constructor you take `Strip` class by copy. Then, in your example you have 2 instances of `Stripe`: one in the global context, and one inside the `Cluster`. You invoke `Stripe::setup` (which calls `FastLED.addLeds`) on the instance in the global context (registering the address of the `Stripe::leds`public field in the FastLED library), but later you call `rgb` on the instance that lives inside your `Cluster` and has different `Stripe::leds` field.

To fix it quickly (not very clean, though), you can redesign your constructor to accept a reference instead of copy:

```
class Cluster {
  public:
    T& strip;
    int first;
    int last;

    Cluster(T& s, int f, int l): strip(s), first(f), last(l) {}
```

Alternatively, you can redesign your architecture a bit more, to not use the templates so much (you can play with `constexpr` arguments instead).

Comment: I must agree with pptaszni that templates are not the best idea here. One approach that has worked for me is class inheritance. Basically create your own class that inherits all the members from the base class, FastLED. The constructor from the new class (Strip, in your case) can define the number of LEDs and any other particular properties for your own implementation